# We need to formalize a site title/name. Does "Database Administrators" still ring true?

Tags: discussion, site-definition

We had some original thoughts here: [Why Database Administrators?](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/why-database-administrators) but that seems to read more of a "why is this site named this way" and not so much of a "we need this name". So I'm making this thread as a "we need this name".

I'm going to copy over each of the old names from the other thread and we can vote on them anew and get some ideas in mind on what the names *mean*.

> Talking about databases is not only the administration side it's all the tasks around them, including:
>
> Data modeling, SQL problems, Database decisions, etc...

#### Please feel free to submit your own suggestions and vote on the ones you like

***These are CW after all.***

--edit by Jack

Two blog posts that are really required reading for anyone who feels strongly about the sites name [here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/stack-exchange-naming-for-dummies/) and [here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/domain-names-the-wrong-question/)

Feedback from various mods on other sites where they have bee through naming issues at length:

> "There is some long history on the naming stuff, currently no SE 2.0 site (except AskUbuntu) gets their own domain, and only very few a non-descriptive name."

> "clarify that [we need] a "nickname", just a generic name that properly describes the audience."

Comment: I don't actually know that the site DNS can change, I'm just putting it out there in case it _can_

Comment: Just had a question about the domains. Will we get a toplevel domain, or be forever stuck in servitude as a subdomain of SE? :)

Comment: @DTest - Useful info on that in one of the links on jcolebrand's other question: [The 7 Essential Meta Questions of Every Beta](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/)

Comment: Is this a settled question?  As in, is "Database Administrators" the final name?

Comment: @Nick I don't think so, but ...

Comment: The more I think about this, the more I favour something in a similar vain to serverfault.com.

Comment: Any further traction on this question? Are we doing anything with it?

Comment: If we want a title to humor with it, why not pick something like tablespaces or bufferpool or lockwait or something like that?

Comment: Because those things only apply to certain types of database systems, and we're interested in a lot more than that.

Comment: This has been open for two years now. I suggest we either move on it, or we close it. Personally, I think we should just leave our name the way it is now that we have been here long enough.

Comment: @ChrisAldrich feel free to flag stuff like this to be closed, we don't mind. But we do want them to be available to the site at large for a while (which this one has been) :D

Answer (score 28):

## Databases

### db.stackexchange.com

Comment: Apparently this was our original name too. IMO if we're going to change it this makes the most sense as there's no fussing about what's a "data guru" or other vague terms. Simple, descriptive, powerful.

Comment: This. We do databases, no frill necessary.

Comment: This this this this.

Comment: This should be the one. Is there something holding us back?

Comment: @Erwin I like this too - but I think [SE doesn't](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/72866/166851)

Comment: Not keen on this. It sounds a bit trite - like a forum for MS-Access noob questions maybe.

Answer (score 16):

### Database Architecture and Management

dba.stackexchange.com

Tagline: Q&A on Database design, management, B.I. systems and advanced server-side development.

Comment: Aha!  We keep the domain name but replace the contentious "Administrators" in our name with something more appropriate. I like it.

Comment: Yours and the one above it (the db3a) ones I think more accurately try to capture the spirit of the site, which is what I was hoping for.

Comment: I really like this one.

Comment: Although 'everybody's an architect' these days in I.T. (at least job-title wise) I think the term 'architecture' is neutral enough and  retains enough gravitas that it doesn't sound too wannabee-ish.

Comment: In practice I'd rate this title about a B+, because Architecture is a fairly debased term in I.T. circles.  However, IMO it's the best of a lot of bad choices - at least the best I can think of.

Comment: database architecture and management network just because I want the url to be damn.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 14):

The current name:

## Database Administrators

#### dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: [Read here why we should replace this name.](http://meta.dba.stackexchange.com/q/495/2660)

Comment: This does cause confusion.  And now that migration is officially not flavour of the month, I suspect that the 'what's in a name' question is more important than it used to be.

Answer (score 5):

## Database Professionals

#### dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Possible future meta questions: Y U HAVE TITEL Database Professionals AND (SUB)DOMAIN AS DBA?

Comment: This is a great question @gbn but at the same time, we want to keep the name "professional" to reflect that what we do is of high caliber.

Comment: @jcolebrand: true, *Data* Professionals covers NoSQL and BI better though

Comment: And yet nobody is voting that one up. I suppose because they can't disassociate the given URL suggestion from the name.

Comment: I disagree with this one because I don't feel it's a real term. Lots of developers do "a little bit of DBA", some DBA do a little bit of development (especially in small shops) but I don't think there are many "database professionals" that are not either DBAs are developers. We are a DBA site that is welcome to questions by developers who operate on databases.

Comment: That's a great point Ben.

Comment: As a side note, *all* SE sites have generally maintained that they are for professionals. Programmers.SE is for "professional programmers" but the site remains just "programmers" not "Senior Programmers" or "Professional Programmers".

Comment: I'm a developer and a member of both this site AND stack overflow. I tend to come here for anything related to databases as opposed to program logic, because I believe the audience here will better answer my questions. I do want to comment though that for some reason Database Professionals just feels more intimidating to me, like I shouldn't join or post a question if I'm not one, imo. I might be the only one, but that's my thought. I just like Database Administrators better and thus I upvoted it.

Comment: Yeah, I had that same issue with MetaSO when I first came to it. That passes. How do we beat that hump @ChrisAldrich?

Comment: @jcolebrand see my suggestion below.

Comment: Again, a bit trite. Using 'professional' in a title is a bit debased, I think. A lot of not-so-professional entities use the term 'professional' to try and big themselves up. My intuitive feel is that using 'professional' in the title has connotations of that.  It sounds a bit try-hard.

Answer (score 4):

### Database Architecture, Analytics and Administration (DB3A)

db3a.stackexchange.com

A variant on some earlier options.

Tagline: Q&A on Database design, administration, B.I. systems and advanced server-side development.

Comment: Does explicitly include B.I. in the title, but I think that Database Architecture and Management is better in practice.

Answer (score 3):

### **Data Technologies**

datatech.stackexchange.com

If the concern is about the scope of the site being greater than just databases and database administrators, then why not place the focus on the technology, rather than the people. This may place a correct light on the types of questions to be submitted here, and without reference to a "DBA" explicitly, perhaps remove the wrong perceptions of DBA's. This may sound less "intimidating" to developers, IT managers, etc. and may feel more open to a wider audience.

(this based off of my comment to jcolebrand's submissions of "Database Professionals"

Comment: Although I'm advocating a title including with word 'architecture', which is bordering on PHB-speak in its own right, I think 'technologies' sounds a bit trite in this context.

Answer (score 2):

## Database Professionals

#### dbpros.stackexchange.com

Per [DTest's suggestion](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270/we-need-to-formalize-a-site-title-name-does-database-administrators-still-ring/271#271).

Answer (score 1):

## Data Gurus

I'm about even on the desire to change the URL to support this. I don't think it benefits anything overall. Alternately, I would like to the URL changed to something indicating data, but data.se is right out. And gurus.se is just not gonna look good either (to my eyes anyways)

So why "Data Gurus"? Well, for starters, it entertains the NoSQL camp to come over, as this site is for both traditional and modern database systems (and all the big vendors are working on side-by-side NoSQL and SQL solutions anyways).

Next up is the point that we are about data, first and foremost. If you really wanted to get into the mechanics of filesystems, we would probably be ok with that here, as it's one of the few places where indexing and rapidly locating information can be discussed academically (besides cstheory).

So, Data, Traditional and Modern data storage, *not-the-words-dba*, Gurus. That's us. That's what we do. Regardless of what the badge we wear during the day says.

Comment: Also avoids the pretentiousness of "Professionals".

Comment: This is good too. @NickChammas: with you on this no pretentions

Comment: +1 I think this one best encompasses everything from BI and NoSQL to OODB and standard RDBMS. It allows for the fact that we fall all along the spectrum from 100% development to 100% "actual" administration. And it nicely sidesteps the pro/enthusiast divide where Professionals draws a line. Plus, there is a certain "wisdom" to good database problem solving that is totally guru-like.

Comment: I just don't think it sounds serious enough. But maybe that is just me.

Comment: @Chris have you seen the chat channel? ;-) I'm sure we would love to have you about over there as well. I'm definitely on track with a lot of your suggestions, I just don't know what to call it in the first place, so have to throw something out at some point.

Comment: Won't work while I'm at work. But maybe some chance I can hop over there during off hours.

Comment: That works too. Just thought I would toss it out at someone who was interested enough to propose several alterations/commentary on meta.

Comment: 'Gurus' sounds a bit try-hard, a bit like 'professionals', although not quite the same aesthetic.  However, I think it's not really quite the right look and feel.  Too cutesy, I think.

Answer (score 0):

### **Database Advice**

**dba.stackexchange.com** (or **dbadvice.stackexchange.com**)

*Database design, architecture, administration, tuning, querying and... anything else you can think of relating to databases and data.*

Sticking with the idea of keeping the domain name but replacing 'Administrators' to make it sound less intimidating. Hopefully still sounding professional/expert, but not scaring anyone off, and appealing to enthusiasts? But is it too vague and wish-washy? And I'm not sure if the domain name itself will discourage people before they have a chance to find out it's not just about traditional 'DBA' stuff.

Comment: Sounds to me like an advice column then. No offense.

Comment: None taken *8-)

Answer (score -1):

### **Data Monkeys**

**datamonkeys.stackexchange.com**

Or maybe "Database Monkeys", "Data Apes" etc

This avoids the potential "DBA" stigma that could scare away NoSQL or BI. Data Professionals is a tad pretentious IMO.

Edit:

- I'm more serious then joking
- My profile says "Code monkey"

Why?

- It isn't pretentious
- Easy to remember/unforgettable
- Mildly amusing
- Self depreciating
- None of our target audience will *actually* think it demeaning
- The name itself will generate traffic
- ...

[image]

Comment: Hmm, I like the attempt to remove DBA stigma on NoSQL, etc. But disagree with the name regardless (doesn't imply 'expert' to me)

Comment: This squarely addresses [my biggest concern](http://meta.dba.stackexchange.com/questions/439/2011-moderator-election-town-hall-chat-digest/447#447) for this site.

Comment: +1 because we are of course all joking, right?

Comment: @JackDouglas - I'm not. :) I think we have a serious problem in looking like (and being) just another bunch of old-school RDBMS dudes.

Comment: @Nick ok, but monkeys? I'm pretty sure gbn was joking :)

Comment: I don't think he was _entirely_ joking on this. I do agree we need to remove the stigma associated with only being stodgy ole dba guys.

Comment: It could work for an established brand with recognition outside the semantics of its name, but I think it's a bit cutesy in practice.

Answer (score -2):

### Data Experts

Q&A for all things data (Expert knowledge in systems for: storage, retrieval & manipulation)

Comment: Except we won't be fielding questions like "which filesystem should I choose when I need real time synchronization across a machine mesh"

Answer (score -6):

### **Database Corrupted**

### dbc.stackexchange.com

We have encountered problems such as stack overflow and server fault. Why not add another?

Comment: Because we are looking to add Business Intelligence to the site, amongst other topics, and the site is about maintenance and administration of databases, as well as more advanced topics.

Answer (score -7):

## Database Administrators and Data Gurus

or

## DBAs and Data Gurus

#### dba.stackexchange.com

*Addressing the name scope problem without a jarring change if/when we switch.*

Comment: I feel the "And" clause is suitable for a tagline but not the site name (though I don't like the name "data gurus"). A name should be concise, accurate and catchy, not all inclusive. Programmers.SE is not Programmers, Systems Analysts and Software QA Gurus.

Comment: just for reference, [here](http://stackexchange.com/sites) is a list of the other SE sites (some of which have longish names)

Answer (score -7):

### data.stackexchange.com

This SE contains questions of a database administration nature, but also OLAP, data warehousing, even NOSQL (Not Only). Data generalizes and expands to fit a wider range of topics.

Comment: Domain [already exists](http://data.stackexchange.com) for a different purpose.

Comment: Something I should have checked before posting ;)

Answer (score -8):

## Stackexchange Database Wonks

dbwonk.stackexchange.com

Comment: +1 for the cuteness, -1 for it's not likely to be a reasonable name in the long run

Answer (score -8):

## Database Queries

query.stackexchange.com, dbq.stackexchange.com.

Apologies for the suggestion spam.

Comment: no no no no no no no... this would give entirely the wrong impression to people. I see what you're going for, and maybe for the URL slug, query might be good.

Answer (score -9):

## Data Whisperer

I did think of calling a consultancy 'Data Whisperer' at one point (oblique reference to the various %Whisperer TV programmes).

Answer (score -9):

## Query Analysers

qa.stackexchange.com (if not taken), quan, try to avoid anything containing 'anal', for obvious reasons