# Database Administrators logo design

Tags: discussion, design

As [mentioned on the site design thread](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313/design-for-database-administrators/325#325), I don't quite understand the purpose of the blue covering (orange earlier) around the logo. IMO, it shouldn't be there.

If it has to be, don't you think the blue is a little too opaque? It would look better if it was a lot more transparent.

Here is a very rough comparison:

[image]
[image]

I just removed the blue boundary and added a little contrast.

What does everyone else think?

Comment: hey @Jin, do we have a plan for this?

Answer (score 6):

The outer cylinder is needed I think: either as outline or very translucent

Comment: Yeah, I would like to see it there and very translucent. What I would ostensibly like to see is the gear done in orange (or the underlying disk below the gear and the other two in blue) and the covering very translucent with a hard border on the edges (like 2px and darker than the discs)

Comment: +1 for less alpha

Answer (score 6):

I'm no designer, but I wonder if the logo design is just too complicated. Especially as a favicon, it tends to blur into an indistinct shape.

Perhaps something much much simpler would be better? Here's my hamfisted attempt:

[image: Cylinder] 
or
[image]
favicon size:
[image]
or:
[image]

I meant to match the colors with the current logo but gave up after 15 minutes trying and failing! Perhaps the swirls should be darker, lighter, thicker, thinner, more or less sketchy or whatever, but hopefully this gets the idea across and crucially would be as recognizable at all the scales it is used at (from favicon to t-shirt)

Comment: +1 simple but effective, i like this much more.  I am really not liking the original logo it is just plain ol ugly.