# What kind of DB diagram is the menu at the top of the page?

Tags: discussion, design

the menu at the top of the page looks like a database diagram.  It isn't crows foot, so what is it?

It kind of looks like the way I map my queries out...but I use a combination of the UML and the Database templates in dia.

Comment: Isn't it the famed Injured Crow Foot Notation?

Comment: When you say "menu", do you mean the Questions/Tags/Users/Badges... part? So you're asking about the site design, yes?

Answer (score 2):

Looking back, the main place I see this discussed previously is as part of our graduation proces:

[Design for Database Administrators](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313/design-for-database-administrators)

It seems the designer drew inspiration from various ER diagram types. One answer there (not from the designer) mentions "crows feet connectors".

Perhaps [Jin](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/users/100/jin) will remember more and post a more complete answer here.

Answer (score -3):

It's a load of CSS and HTML, so it's actually off-topic for this site.